# Windows Powershell script to alter table

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I have below script, named as alterTable.ps1. I am trying to alter table by adding two new columns to table.

**Here is script**

```
function die {
    "Error: $($args[0])"
    exit 1
}
function verifySuccess {
    if (!$?) {
        die "$($args[0])"
    }
}
# Create variables and assign environment variables
$INSTANCE_HOST = $env:HOST
$INSTANCE_PORT = $env:PORT
$INSTANCE_NAME = $env:INSTANCE
$DATABASE_NAME = $env:DATABASE_NAME
# Execute the alter table, passing the variables
#sqlcmd -U sa -P sapassword -S "$INSTANCE_HOST\$INSTANCE_NAME,$INSTANCE_PORT" -q ”use $DATABASE_NAME; ALTER TABLE dbo.tabletest ADD Test1 VARCHAR(6) NULL, Test2 VARCHAR(10) NULL”
VerifySuccess "sqlcmd failed to alter table tabletest"
```

When I execute script with values passing to script, getting error

```
C:\> .\alterTable.ps1 "WINDOWSHOST" "1433" "MSSQLSERVER" "dbname"
```

Getting error as below:

> HResult 0x57, Level 16, State 1 SQL Server Network Interfaces:
>   Connection string is not valid [87]. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific
>   error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   Server is not found or not accessible.

If I hardcode those values in script, then it worked fine.

One more quick thing, how I can exit script after execution and check the exit status?

Comment: Where do you assign values to environment variables?

Comment: The second question is somewhat unclear. A powershell-script exits by itself when it's done (all lines are executed). If you want to check if your `die`-function ended it, check `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` if you're calling it from batch, process exit code etc. depending on what the parent process/caller is. If `die` stopped it, the exit code should be 1.

Comment: What does `write-host "$INSTANCE_HOST\$INSTANCE_NAME,$INSTANCE_PORT"` give you?

Comment: Thanks PerSerAl, Frode and Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never accessing the arguments that you pass to the script, but rather reading the values from four environment-variables (that you never set?). You should be using parameters with default values set to the values of the environment variables if necessary. Ex:

```
param(
    $INSTANCEHOST = $env:HOST,
    $INSTANCEPORT = $env:PORT,
    $INSTANCENAME = $env:INSTANCE,
    $DATABASENAME = $env:DATABASE_NAME
)

function die {
    "Error: $($args[0])"
    exit 1
}
function verifySuccess {
    if (!$?) {
        die "$($args[0])"
    }
}

# Execute the alter table, passing the variables
sqlcmd -U sa -P sapassword -S "$INSTANCEHOST\$INSTANCENAME,$INSTANCEPORT" -q ”use $DATABASENAME; ALTER TABLE dbo.tabletest ADD Test1 VARCHAR(6) NULL, Test2 VARCHAR(10) NULL”
VerifySuccess "sqlcmd failed to alter table tabletest"
```

Use it like this:

```
C:\> .\alterTable.ps1 -INSTANCEHOST "WINDOWSHOST" -INSTANCEPORT "1433" -INSTANCENAME "MSSQLSERVER" -DATABASENAME "dbname"
```

Comment: Thanks Frode. I got the hint.